# Difference between Game1.GraphicsDevice and graphics.GraphicsDevice

Tags: c#, graphics, xna

In XNA 4.0, what's the difference between the GraphicsDevice property of my game class and the GraphicsDevice property of the "graphics" variable? BTW, "graphics" is of type GraphicsDeviceManager.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing. Try it yourself:

```
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(graphics.GraphicsDevice, this.GraphicsDevice));
```

Put that somewhere like inside `LoadContent`. You will find that it outputs `true`. They both refer to the same object.

For the sake of readability, you should generally use `Game.GraphicsDevice`.

---

The underlying behaviour is that `GraphicsDeviceManager` is an `IGraphicsDeviceService` (which provides a `GraphicsDevice` member). When you create `GraphicsDeviceManager`, it adds itself to `Game.Services` in its constructor (see how you pass a reference to your `Game` into its constructor).

`Game` sets its `GraphicsDevice` member from any `IGraphicsDeviceService` in its `Services` list. That way, you can replace `GraphicsDeviceManager` with your own class that implements `IGraphicsDeviceService` - if you happen to be crazy ;)

`GraphicsDeviceManager` is also a `IGraphicsDeviceManager`, which `Game` uses in a similar way (through `Game.Services`) to manage creating the graphics device.

Answer (score 0):

GraphicsDeviceManager manage GraphicsDevice and you shouldn't use GraphicsDevice directly. It could be changed so instead of it just use GraphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice property if you need.